# Why isn't stage global?

Tags: actionscript-3, global-variables, stage

I wonder what benefits gives making stage non-static reference in each object instead of making it global. Because of that I have only problems with dereferencing null. But, there must be case why Adobe crew made it that way. So, can someone explain me that behaviour? And what problems can I have when I use something like the following code, and use gStage everywhere I need stage?

```
package
{
    public var gStage: Stage;
    public class Main extends Sprite;
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            if (stage)
                init();
            else
                stage.addEventListener (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
        public static function init(): void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            gStage = stage;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, why in every AS3 code sample I've ever seen Main extends Sprite?

Comment: Why *should* the stage be global?

Comment: That's gonna throw a nullpointer exception. First you make sure stage == null and then you call a function on it.

Comment: globals (often) break the object-oriented programming paradigm.  just put everything on the same stage and use Event objects for communication.  samples called Main that extend Sprite are certainly the document / controller class, which already have been added and have access to the stage.  you should read some books on AS3 - there's a lot to know and the googling for answers isn't a smart way to understand the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although each Flash movie usually has a single stage on which visible display objects are drawn, there is not just a single "global" stage in AIR applications; each window has its own stage, and hence each window object has to have its own instance reference to its own stage. It wouldn't be right to make a single static global stage object in that case — what if an AIR application requires multiple windows?

Comment: AIR is a great example. Further details that might be useful: the stage property is only available on display objects. Each display object contains a reference to the stage, but it will be null if the display object is not on the display list (eg actually attached to the stage). Same with the 'root' property on display objects.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked above, "Why should stage be global?"
A : I don't think it *should* be global, but here is a simple use case where global access to the Stage is mighty useful :
Finding the available pixels to layout ( position, size ) the DisplayObject and/or its visual assets *before it is added to the display list*.

I sometimes have layout classes that don't extend `DisplayObject` and get references to DisplayObjects to layout *before* the `DisplayObject`has been added to the display list - and so therefore has no **`stage`** property of it's own yet.
Using my method below I can always know the current available pixels any time after the main document class has a **`stage`** property and calls
`GlobalReference.global.stage = stage;`

```
var screenWidth : uint = GlobalReference.global.stage.stageWidth;
var screenHeight : uint = GlobalReference.global.stage.stageHeight;
```

!! WARNING !! globals are dangerous and easy to misuse

I add references to the 'global' object ( very carefully and thoughtfully ) so that I can access them from any class - and particularly be able to access it in a closure or anonymous function.  Closures don't need to call the static getter because they are in the global scope already.

```
package com.appcloud9.utils
{
    public class GlobalReference
    {
        public static function get global() : Object
        {
            // may be superstition, but I *think* that assigning the function
            // to a var is better for garbage collection later
            var getGlobal : Function = function() : Object
            {
                return this;
            };
            return getGlobal();
        }
    }
}

// usage examples :

// I call this in my main document class on the Event.EXIT_FRAME event :
GlobalReference.global.stage = stage;

// later in a closure
var signalLightsOut = new Signal();
signalLightsOut.add( function() : void
{
    trace( stage );                        // [object Stage]
} );

// later in a constructor - before the class has a stage of it's own
public function MyConstructor()
{
    trace( stage );                        // null
    trace( GlobalReference.global.stage ); // [object Stage]
    /* note : it is usually best and fully adequate to wait until a class extending
        DisplayObject has its own stage : after Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE and then
        Event.EXIT_FRAME it is guaranteed. */
}
```